# Difference between distribution and random variable

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

The definition of distribution is(as far as I know) "a function that maps the outcome of an event to it's probability" and all the definitions of random variable I've come across say almost the same. So what is the difference?

Comment: Citation. Citation. Citation.

Comment: @User1865345-solidarityMods "A random variable is a numerical description of the outcome of a statistical experiment" or "it is a function from possible outcomes in a sample space to a measurable space"

Comment: I've never seen a definition of a random variable that says, even approximately, that it's "a function that maps the outcome of an event to it's probability."

Comment: "A numerical description" does not equal "it's probability", nor does "a measurable space".

Comment: @jbowman, so explain me what is random variable actually is in simple terms

Comment: Take a coin flip:  heads or tails.  The R.V. maps this to 0 or 1, one way or another, but the probabilities aren't 0 or 1.   Or "height"; the R.V. maps this to "5'3"", which is not a probability.

Comment: @jbowman, so random variable is a function that assigns numbers to the outcomes of an event. Is my definition right?

Comment: Not *quite*, the numbers that can be assigned have to have, collectively, the property of being a measurable space.   For most practical purposes, this is ignorable.

Comment: This is two questions, because neither definition is correct.  For what a random variable is, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50.  For what a distribution is, there are too many posts to mention, but quite a few of the hits on [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=distribution+defin*+F_X+is%3Aanswer) will give you an answer.  I suspect your question might originate in multiple senses of "distribution" that include (1) a (discrete) *probability distribution* and (2) the *distribution function* of a random variable.